# Google Play Billing 2.0 testing pending transactions and acknowledgement

Tags: android, google-play, android-billing, play-billing-library

I'm transitioning to Google Play Billing library v2.0.0 and there are two major flow differences. One is purchase acknowledgment https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#acknowledge and the other is handling pending transactions https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#pending.

For pending transactions the docs state that

> In addition to two test credit cards, license testers have access to two test instruments for delayed forms of payment which automatically complete or cancel after a couple of minutes

...but I only have access to two regular test cards, no delayed ones.

And also that:

> For purchases made by license testers, the acknowledgement window is shorter. Instead of three days, purchases are refunded and revoked if they are not acknowledged within five minutes.

But I still get 6x 5-minute long renewals for a monthly subscription, so a regular behavior, not the new one.

Of course I called `enablePendingPurchases()` upon init.

Clearly the new flow is not enabled for me, but why is that?

Comment: hi, did you find out what was wrong ?

Comment: I have just revisited and the acknowledgement just started working. If I don't ack the purchase, the subscription page in consumer google play says that I need to reopen app, otherwise the purchase will not complete and on test account it expires after 3 minutes or so. So this is fine. But still no idea how to enable pending purchase testing, I still only have two test cards.